# Can I create a batch file using pascal?

Tags: batch-file, pascal

Using pascal, can I create a text and then save it like a .bat file ? Example:

```
Program Program_;
uses dos;
var ......
begin
assign(TEXT,'TEXT.txt');
rewrite(TEXT);
writeln(TEXT,' **Enter here all commands of the .bat file that I want create** ');
close(TEXT);
```

and then save the file TEXT.bat that I had yet create as a .bat file ?
Example:

```
Create(FILEBAT.bat);                     ] I know those commands are absurd I invet 
FILEBAT:= 'TEXT'    ;                    ] them right now.
end.
```

How can I do it ?????

Comment: Just use `assign(TEXT,'TEXT.BAT')` and write all commands. No need to copy/transform the TXT file to a BAT file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is easy because you can make batch files only by using a Text Editor. So what you have to do is to create a file with the .bat extension on it.
Then you have to write your code in this file.

For Example:

```
program MakeBatchFiles;
var
   batchfile : text;
begin
   Assign(batchfile, 'mybatchfile.bat'); rewrite(batchfile);
   write(batchfile, 'echo This is a batch file.');
   close(batchfile);
end.
```

Just make a text file with the .bat extension on it, as you would normally do if you were making it with a text editor.